# iFrame - JavaScript to delete elements

Tags: html, iframe, relative-path

I have the following problem: We have two sites, one community page based on elgg and a second page based on typo3. What we want to do is create a simple iframe in a typo3 subpage, which contain the community page. 
Since the community page has its own page header with logos etc, it looks stupid. I tried to delete everything expect the , but this is not possible because the iframe source looks like "http://myiFramePage.org", so they do not have the same origin. 
Fortunately, the two systems are on the same server, but i was not able to create a relative url. Could you help me to find the right url?

- /

  - public_html

    - elgg

      - index.php
    - typo3

      - index.php

Also i would like to ask what do you think? Does it make sence to cut out the body/most important parts of the page?

Answer (score 0):

If you just cutout the body from elgg and call it inside typo, it wont work. Because its missing css, essential js files etc. 
The best solution is to create a similar theme for the community site too. This will make both site looking the same and you wont loose any functionality of community site.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like solutions which hack things, they have a tendency to break, and are virtually untestable.  I would try to customize the internal page from within the system (as suggested in Webgalli's answer) to make it look like the outer page.